# language detection and url rewrite/redirection

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

My website has two languages: EN (English) and TR (Turkish)
Now, it is loading as Turkish as default language. There is no any language phrase in the urls. For example our pages like: domain.com/index.php, domain.com/aboutus.php, etc..

If somebody click the "English" link, then page reload with this phrase: ?language=EN. For example domain.com/aboutus.php?language=EN

After this click, all pages loads as English but we don't see any language phrases in the url too. The other pages loading like services.php, contact.php normally but English..

I need a simple browser language redirector:
- If a user's browser language is Turkish, then everything is ok, page can load as default Turkish language.
- If a user's browser language is not Turkish, then pages should load as English via ?language=EN phrase. For example domain.com/aboutus.php?language=EN

The important thing is, this control should happen when first visit of any page (not only index). If a user choose Turkish, then we shouldn't load English pages again.

We can use for this php, htaccess or javascript.

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if the syntax was symmetric (i.e. you have the same thing for Turkish that you have for English). If that looks ugly, (and it does to me), move that to the session. I propose this is sufficiently clean:

1. If the request is the language change request, change the language, save to session. Otherwise,
2. If the session contains the language choice, use that language. Otherwise,
3. Use `Accept-Language` header to figure out what the browser wants, set the language, save to session.

You can, of course, use the same system with an URL parameter. The problem is, with your current scheme, you can't differentiate between "no language selected" and "English selected".

Comment: Thanks for your answer and solution. Your suggestion is too hard for me unfortunately. If you want, you can see my language selection codes on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819454/script-can-not-load-language-phrases-properly-from-database-when-first-visit#

Comment: Which bit is too hard? If it's parsing `Accept-Language`, you can find a nice PHP parser [here](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header). (There are only two ways to detect user's language, both fallible, and the other one is geolocation by IP.) The rest should be rather trivial to do.

Comment: sessions, rules, etc.. All of them :) Thanks for your answer. Maybe I need a smarty expert with payment option :)